# preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true" not working for upgrade

Tags: android, target-sdk

I recently upgraded the target SDK to 30 (the current version is 28). In order to migrate data, I configured `preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the AndroidManifest. I hope to migrate files from external storage to internal storage. However, on many devices where I perform an overlay installation of the application, I still encounter exceptions related to reading and writing external storage. The return value of `Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()` is also false. Can you help identify the issue?

The android os version of the test device is Android R.

AndroidManifest.xml config:

```
 <application
...
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
```

Comment: You did not tell Android version(s) of used devices.

Comment: Sorry , I run the app on the Android R device

Comment: So that is Android 11? You updated your app. But was the Android version of the device updated too? Was it Q/10 before?

Comment: No ,  the version of the mobile operating system has always been Android 11.  I just upgrade the target sdk of my app from 28 to 30

Comment: Well then you have nothing to do with requestLegacyExternalStorage and the other as that has only effect on Android Q/10 devices.

Comment: yes, but  preserveLegacyExternalStorage does not working too for the upgrade app user

Comment: Indeed. I said 'and the other'. Forget about them.